# Should development team leaders be line managers?

Tags: team-management, leadership, technical-leader

In a development team with a leader, should this leader be a line manager or is it better to separate the two roles?

How much admin/HR should a hands-on leader actually do before it becomes the responsibility of somebody else?

Comment: Please provide more details: what size is the team, what is the reporting structure above the team, is the organisation familiar with "matrix" responsibilities or is it very hierarchic, what is in place just now, and how well is the current structure working? (or to put it another way, what problem are you trying to solve?)

Comment: @Iain9688 Things are subject to change. We are a young company and growing fast. We have 15x developers and growing. We currently have a CTO and two development managers (team leader, line manager, scrum master, etc). This is a hierarchical structure. This question is a spin off from my other question [here](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/9221/4342).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a PM question. Could you establish why this question belongs in PM:SE rather than in management or workplace SE?  Is this a question about how to manage a project, or about HR, Management and Leadership?

Comment: It's a spin off from this [question](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/9221/4342). It is regarding appropriate structure of a development team for effective project management.

Comment: This is really a [Peter Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Principle) question, and should probably be moved to [Workplace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) if it's on-topic there.

Comment: @CodeGnome This is definitely not a Peter Principle question. I'm not asking about capability, but rather merits for and against development team leaders taking on adminstrative/hr/line management duties. Is it productive? Is it a bad idea?

Comment: I`d say most of the answers we'll have for this question will have a level of bias based on each company culture, therefore will be hard to reach a valid and objective answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an advocate of **not** having people reporting into other members of their immediate team.  Having a line manager in the room can affect the honesty of things like retrospectives and it avoids some awkward situations (would you want to pair program with someone who just put you/you just put on performance review?).

At my place, we have a **lead developers** who provide **technical leadership** to the team they work in and **managing developers** who people outside of their immediate team report into for the **career development** aspects (and managing lead devs who do technical leadership for their team **and** line manage people outside it).

Added following question in comments:

People have regular catch ups with their line managers and I think it's helpful to be able to ask for advice about an issue within the team from someone who isn't emotionally involved in the problem.

I don't think most people really view it as an employee/employer relationship.  It's more like having an impartial peer you can talk to about problems and development.  Probably more accurate to call them mentors rather than line managers for the most part although they are expected to tackle issues like lateness/sickness where the team are unable to do so themselves.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Does that limit the development of relationships between employee and employer? If the developer is detached from their manager, how can the manager know when/how to deal with changes, e.g. promotions,  training, personal issues, etc. It seems to me that relationship would be build inside the team but not with the manager. The manager would presumably become detached from the staff. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Will add to my answer as the comment was getting long!

Comment: My answer to your previous question (http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/how-to-structure-a-software-development-team) talks about Squad management, which encourages chapter (i.e. skill grouping) leads to deal with line management _across_ squads (i.e. project teams). I think this broadly aligns with Ben's points.

Comment: @Willl That's my evening reading material. This is something that I've had thoughts on but never seen a formal approach to.

Answer (score 3):

Team Leaders and Line Managers are different depending on your organisation structure.

A **Line Manager** is generally used in a vertical structure with responsibility for direct supervision of line workers, in this case, developers. They duties such as scheduling, training, hiring, firing and writing performance evaluations.

A **Team Leader** works a lot closer with colleagues to provide motivation for team members. There may be some administrative duties like scheduling, but is generally not considered as a supervisor to colleagues.

I guess your question is more to do with developers fitting into either of these roles and where you want your better developers to be.

The more knowledgeable/senior developers would be more suited to the team leader role being able to provide technical consultation and also meaning they wouldn't have the burden of carrying out as many administrative duties as a line manager.

A lot depends on the ambitions of the "better" developers, whether they want to continue to do what they enjoy doing as developers or if they want to move into more administrative line manager role.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any reason why it is a good idea to separate the roles. In fact, most of the team leaders I know are members of the line organisation. If you think about it, the responsibilities of a leader is quite the same as the responsibilities of a line manager. For example: the general "well being" of the team members, technical and personal growing, motivation etc.

The leadership has nothing to do with "admin". So answering the question you need none, but then you can an ask, "what do I need then?" Unfortunately, that question is too general, and I cannot answer.

Comment: Based on your answer, do you think it's a good or bad idea for the **strongest** developer to be the leader/manager? Considering this role has less time allocated for actual development.

Comment: definitely not unless she has management ambitions. She became the strongest, because she likes what she is doing. Promotion means that she will have to do something different, and there is a chance that she'll look for another opportunity, where she can continue to do what she likes. Make her a tech lead, and find somebody who'll do the administration part.

Comment: Totally agree with that.  I've seen too many unhappy (former) devs who have stumbled into management and don't get the time to do the stuff they like any more.